# Симметричность массива на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Преподаватель по программированию, сказала, что симметрия массива проверяется по этому коду:

```
int a[10];
bool f=true;
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++) //если в массиве будет нечетное число, то, до какое условие должно стоять в for?
if (a[i]!=a[10-i-1]) //что означает вот эта строчка?
{
f=false;
break;
}
if (f) cout<<"Yes"<<endl;//как решать без bool, а то путаюсь в true и false.
else
cout<<"No"<<endl;
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить закоментированные строки и привести пример проверки на симметрию без bool, пожалуйста?

Comment: Почему эти вопросы не задать преподавательнице?

Comment: Потому что она негативно реагирует на вопросы и не очень понятно объясняет(

Comment: Когда возникают вопросы особенно когда вы начинающий - попробуйте поискать в интернете, на них давно уже есть ответы. Не ленитесь, потом этот навык пригодится. Запрос "с++ !="

Comment: Попробуйте выписать значения `i` для этого цикла на бумажку и внимательно посмотрите на получившийся ряд чисел

Comment: Кстати, вот такой цикл для сравнения `for (int i = FIRST, j = LAST; i < j; i++, j--) if (a[i] != a[j]) { f = false; break; }` более очевиден. Тут сразу видно что мы "сжигаем свечу сразу с обеих концов". Запомните этот прием, он еще неоднократно может вам встретиться

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если код немного переписать, станет более понятно:

```
const int MAX_SIZE_ARRAY = 10;
int a[MAX_SIZE_ARRAY];
bool symmetrically = true; // по умолчанию массив симметричен
const int leftPartArray = MAX_SIZE_ARRAY / 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= leftPartArray; ++i) 
// проверяем симметричность, достаточно подставить 0 для проверки и понять смысл
if (a[i] != a[MAX_SIZE_ARRAY - i - 1]) 
{
// если допустим 0 и 9 элемент не совпадают, массив не симметричный
symmetrically = false;
// выходим
break;
}
if (symmetrically)
cout<< "Symmetrically! "<<endl;
else
cout<<"not Symmetrically!"<<endl;
```

В случае если количество элементов нечетное, надо как-то иначе проверять симметричность, данный вариант не подойдет.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> если в массиве будет нечетное число

возьми 7 кубков и попробуй вручную на них прогнать

> if (a[i]!=a[10-i-1]) //что означает вот эта строчка?

смотрится равны или нет два элемента массива (i-й и такой же симметричный с конца, пробуйте на кубиках или на листочке с квадратиками)

> if (f) .......;//как решать без bool, а то путаюсь в true и false.

никто не запрещает условие делать if (f==true) (правда некоторые привиреды ругаются, что это слишком длинно).

Но с такими вопросами реально нужно к преподу. Если преподаватель возмущается, то жалуйтесь руководству на такого препода.